# Groupby and Compare the results in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following recordset for a given School (i.e., ABC in this example) , I need to groupby on **Class** and **Activity** and take the first row . Then I need to match the 'Activity' of grouped records and check for 'Groups' data (ID 1,4 return true because 'Activity' is 'Dance and Groups is 'B'). If they are same I need to return true.
In this example , I get four records with IDs 1,2,4,5 and since 'Activity' of ID 1,4 are matching and Groups is 'B' , Activity of 2,4 are matching and Groups is same 'B' I need to return true.

```
ID  School  Class  Activity  Groups OtherData
1   ABC      A       Dance     B     Junk1
2   ABC      A       Sing      B     Junk2
3   ABC      A       Sing      B     Junk3
4   ABC      B       Dance     B     Junk4
5   ABC      B       Sing      B     Junk5
```

I am trying to achieve the same using linq ,

```
List<School> schoolList = //from db all 5 records

var result = schoolList.Group(res => {res.School,res.Class}).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList();
```

Further , I am not sure how to check the "Groups" are same for the above grouped records .

Example 2:

```
ID  School  Class  Activity  Groups OtherData
1   ABC      A       Dance     B     Junk1
2   ABC      A       Sing      C     Junk2
3   ABC      A       Sing      C     Junk3
4   ABC      B       Dance     B     Junk4
5   ABC      B       Sing      B     Junk5
```

Here , the result should be false because IDs 2,5 after matching with Activity they have different Groups C and B.

Do I need to use 2 different result sets and join on 'Activity'?

Comment: If you want to group on class and activity why are you grouping on School and Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping by `Class` and `Activity`

```csharp
var rowsDistinctByClassAndActivity = schoolList
    .GroupBy(school => new { school.Class, school.Activity })
    .Select(gr => gr.First());
```

, you could obtain your result by first grouping by `Activity` and then checking if all `Groups` values in each grouping are identical by counting the distinct occurrences of `Groups` for each grouping:

```csharp
var result = rowsDistinctByClassAndActivity
    .GroupBy(row => row.Activity)
    .All(gr => gr.Select(row => row.Groups).Distinct().Count() == 1);
```

The two calculations may be combined:

```csharp
var result = schoolList
    .GroupBy(school => new { school.Class, school.Activity })
    .Select(gr => gr.First())
    .GroupBy(row => row.Activity)
    .All(gr => gr.Select(row => row.Groups).Distinct().Count() == 1);
```

---

A more optimized alternative to counting the distinct occurrences is to check that there are not more than one distinct occurrence of `Groups`. To obtain this, the last line in the previous code could be replaced by:

```csharp
    .All(gr => !gr.Select(row => row.Groups).Distinct().Skip(1).Any());
```

I'd say this is an unnecessary change to make, though, unless you expect that there may be a lot of different `Groups` values present in many of the groupings.

---

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cD3Z7o).